# Performing SQL updates based on row number and using previous row for calculations

Tags: sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a python/pandas code that I was using to perform some calculations, but I was having performance issues with it. I'm trying to write everything on SQL, updating the table with BigQuery.

The problem that I am facing is to update an existing table based on row number and using previous rows for calculations.

The code below is what I was using, and now I need to do this in SQL. "i" is the row number.

```
if i <= 4:
    perfil['B'].iloc[i] = 0
else:
    perfil['B'].iloc[i] = perfil['A'] + perfil['B'].iloc[i - 2]
```

So, for the first 5 rows I do some calculations that don't use previous rows. But after that, the calculation will use previous rows.

My table is already created in this way:

```
| DEPTH_M   | A | B |
|-----------|---|---|
|1.2        |2  |0  |
|1.4        |3  |0  |
|1.6        |6  |0  |
|1.8        |2  |0  |
|2.0        |1  |0  |
|2.2        |6  |0  |
|2.4        |7  |0  |
|2.6        |6  |0  |
```

And after some user input, I need to perform the update in the table using the code that I showed before that results in this:

```
| DEPTH_M   | A | B                                                    |
|-----------|---|------------------------------------------------------|
|1.2        |2  |0                                                     |
|1.4        |3  |0                                                     |
|1.6        |6  |0                                                     |
|1.8        |2  |0                                                     |
|2.0        |1  |0  (Zero till now, first 5 rows are filled with zeros)|
|2.2        |6  |6 (6 from A + 0 from the past two rows)               |
|2.4        |7  |7  (7 from A + 0 from the past two rows)              |
|2.6        |6  |12 (6  from A + 6 from the past two rows)             |
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you are implementing.

Comment: Which version of mysql u r using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the post, sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur actually I'm using Google BigQuery API from a python script.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1.2 DEPTH_M, 2 A, 0 B union all
  select 1.4, 3, 0 union all
  select 1.6, 6, 0 union all
  select 1.8, 2, 0 union all
  select 2.0, 1, 0 union all
  select 2.2, 6, 0 union all
  select 2.4, 7, 0 union all
  select 2.6, 6, 0 union all 
  select 3.0, 1, 0 union all
  select 3.2, 6, 0 union all
  select 3.4, 7, 0 
)
select DEPTH_M, A,  
  ifnull(if(rn <= 5, 0, A) + sum(if(rn <= 5, 0, A)) over win, 0) as B,
  format('%i + %i', if(rn <= 5, 0, A), ifnull(sum(if(rn <= 5, 0, A)) over win, 0)) as expalnation
from (
  select DEPTH_M, A, B,
    row_number() over(order by DEPTH_M) rn
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
window win as (partition by mod(rn, 2) order by rn rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
order by DEPTH_M
```

with output

[image]

In case if you need to update your table  - you can use below

```
update `project.dataset.table` u
set B = s.B
from (
  select  DEPTH_M, A, ifnull(if(rn <= 5, 0, A) + sum(if(rn <= 5, 0, A)) over win, 0) as B 
  from (
    select DEPTH_M, A, B,
      row_number() over(order by DEPTH_M) rn
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
  window win as (partition by mod(rn, 2) order by rn rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
) s
where u.DEPTH_M = s.DEPTH_M
and u.A = s.A;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is implicitly defining a recurrence relation. If you unrolled a single term `Bn` you'd get an expanded expression like this:

[image: equations]

Ultimately each `Bn` descends into a summation of preceding `A` terms (as long as `n > 5`.) Seeing that `B1` through `B5` evaluate to zero when then initial values of the `A` series are forced to be zero, this simple mapping function will work without having to store the outputs iteratively.

Notice that the array indexes (subscripts) to be combined are all offset by consecutive multiples of two. That means they all fall into the same modular congruence class, which is to say that they have the same remainder when divided by two. That's where the partition using `mod()` comes in.

```
with r as ( /* attach row numbers starting with 1 */
    select *, DEPTH_M, A, B, row_number() over (order by DEPTH_M) as rn
    from T
)
select DEPTH_M, A,  
     sum(case when rn > 5 then A else 0 end)
         over (partition by mod(rn, 2) order by rn) as B,
from r
order by DEPTH_M;
```

This query doesn't require the handling of nulls. It works on the default window for `sum() over ()` which includes the current row.